# google maps api v3 dynamic markers, help getting array to work

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-maps-api-3, markers

I am trying to create a google map with javascript api v3. I'm not the best with arrays. the  tag gets pulled in dynamically from another search and outputs the finding in this format. now I need it to take this format and output it to multiple markers on the map. I am having issues getting the array to output correctly. This the the format I would like output from the array ... any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
var locations = [
  ['Bondi Beach', -33.890542, 151.274856, 4],
  ['Coogee Beach', -33.923036, 151.259052, 5],
  ['Cronulla Beach', -34.028249, 151.157507, 3],
  ['Manly Beach', -33.80010128657071, 151.28747820854187, 2],
  ['Maroubra Beach', -33.950198, 151.259302, 1]
```

my code starts here

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html> 
<head> 
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" /> 

  <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false" 
          type="text/javascript"></script>
</head> 
<body>

    <markers>
<marker zip="17507" state="Pennsylvania" city="Bowmansville" address="1363 Bowmansville Rd." county="Lancaster" lng="-76.0134" lat="40.1957" html="Reading Equipment & Distribution (Bowmansville)">    </marker>
<marker zip="18071" state="Pennsylvania" city="Palmerton" address="1226 Little Gap Road" county="Carbon" lng="-75.617" lat="40.8083" html="SMF"></marker>
 <marker zip="18020" state="Pennsylvania" city="Bethlehem" address="2706 Brodhead Road" county="Northampton" lng="-75.3696" lat="40.6269" html="Versalift East, LLC (Specialty)"></marker>
 <marker zip="19720" state="Delaware" city="New Castle" address="203 Pigeon Point Road" county="New      Castle" lng="-75.5954" lat="39.6733" html="Auto Port, Inc."></marker>
     </markers>

   <div id="map" style="width: 500px; height: 400px;"></div>

  <script type="text/javascript">

   var locations = [];
  var iIndex=0;


    var markers = document.getElementsByTagName("marker");
     //var locations;

    for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
          iIndex = i+1;
  }
 // String[] locations = new String[];
    locations.length = iIndex;


   for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
     var name = markers[i].getAttribute("html");
     var address = markers[i].getAttribute("address");
     var city = markers[i].getAttribute("city");
     var state = markers[i].getAttribute("state");
     var zip = markers[i].getAttribute("zip");
      var pointlat = markers[i].getAttribute("lat");
     var pointlng = markers[i].getAttribute("lat");

     locations[i] = [];
     locations[i].length = 4;

     locations[i][0] = name;
      locations[i][1] = pointlat;
      locations[i][2] = pointlng;
     locations[i][3] = '1';

      document.write(locations);

    }



      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
       zoom: 10,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(-76.0134,40.1957),
       mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
     });

     var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

      var marker;

      for (var j = 0; j < locations.length; j++) {  



      marker = new google.maps.Marker({
         position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[j][1], locations[j][2]),
         map: map
       });

          google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, j) {

        return function() {
          infowindow.setContent(locations[j][0]);
          infowindow.open(map, marker);
        }
      })(marker, j));
         }


  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, this bit here is completely redundant:

```
for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
          iIndex = i+1;
  }
 // String[] locations = new String[];
    locations.length = iIndex;
```

As is this:

```
 locations[i].length = 4;
```

You don't have to predefine the length of an array before you populate it.

One issue you might be having, is that reading the values of some markup using getAttribute() will return a string.  So when you try and create a marker, it expects a floating point number, not a string.  So you can convert them to numerics like so:

```
locations[i][1] = parseFloat(pointlat);
locations[i][2] = parseFloat(pointlng);
```

Also, and this is perhaps your main mistake, you're using latitude values for your longitude coordinates!

```
 var pointlng = markers[i].getAttribute("lat");
```

You repeat the error when creating your map, these are the wrong way around:

```
center: new google.maps.LatLng(-76.0134,40.1957),
```

And finally, rather than looping over all your markers to populate 'locations', then looping again over 'locations' to create each marker, I think you could achieve all you need in just one loop.

Here's a complete solution which works for me:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html> 
<head> 
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" /> 
    <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script>
    function initialize() {
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
            zoom: 8,
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(40.1957,-76.0134),
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        });

        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

        var marker;

        var location = {};

        var markers = document.getElementsByTagName("marker");

        for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
            location = {
                name : markers[i].getAttribute("html"),
                address : markers[i].getAttribute("address"),
                city : markers[i].getAttribute("city"),
                state : markers[i].getAttribute("state"),
                zip : markers[i].getAttribute("zip"),
                pointlat : parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lat")),
                pointlng : parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lng"))   
            };

            console.log(location);

            marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: new google.maps.LatLng(location.pointlat, location.pointlng),
                map: map
            });

            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker,location) {
                return function() {
                    infowindow.setContent(location.name);
                    infowindow.open(map, marker);
                };
            })(marker, location));
        }
    }

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    </script>
</head> 
<body>
    <markers>
        <marker zip="17507" state="Pennsylvania" city="Bowmansville" address="1363 Bowmansville Rd." county="Lancaster" lng="-76.0134" lat="40.1957" html="Reading Equipment & Distribution (Bowmansville)">    </marker>
        <marker zip="18071" state="Pennsylvania" city="Palmerton" address="1226 Little Gap Road" county="Carbon" lng="-75.617" lat="40.8083" html="SMF"></marker>
        <marker zip="18020" state="Pennsylvania" city="Bethlehem" address="2706 Brodhead Road" county="Northampton" lng="-75.3696" lat="40.6269" html="Versalift East, LLC (Specialty)"></marker>
        <marker zip="19720" state="Delaware" city="New Castle" address="203 Pigeon Point Road" county="New      Castle" lng="-75.5954" lat="39.6733" html="Auto Port, Inc."></marker>
    </markers>

    <div id="map" style="width: 500px; height: 400px;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```